# Getting the previous route on vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I want to get the previous route when a component loads and I'm trying to achieve that using onBeforeRouteUpdate

```
<script setup>

const previousRoute = ref("");

onBeforeRouteUpdate((to, from, next) => {
    console.log("to:");
    console.log(to);
    console.log("from:");
    console.log(from);
    previousRoute.value = from.name;
    next();
});
</script>

<template>
   
    PREVIOUS ROUTE:{{ previousRoute }}
</template>
```

But the onBeforeRouteUpdate is not being loaded. There is nothing logged in the console and the previous route remains empty. How do I get the previous route?

Comment: Update hook triggers when the same route is updated. I doubt this can be done with script setup alone. Use beforeRouteEnter hook.